# Python3 isnumeric() method not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just getting to explore some other Python methods such as isnumeric(). I have an assignment task where I'm to search and extract numbers from text. I have posted the code below.

```
handle = open("words3.txt")
for line in handle:
   line = line.rstrip()
   split = line.split()
   for word in split:
      x = word.isnumeric()
      print(x)
```

With this I am getting a traceback... But I think I have followed the rules of str.isnumeric(). Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
File "assignment11.py", line 10, in <module>
    x = word.isnumeric()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

Comment: `line.split()` will return the `line` itself. What is the point of this line of code?

Comment: @pavel no, just `.split()` is like `.split(" ")`. So, that may return list of words from `line`.

Comment: @Kshitiz, oh right, thanks. Never used `split()` like this, prefer to always specify.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

`isnumeric()` works on Unicode strings. To define a string as Unicode you could change your string definitions like so:

```
s = u'This is my string'
#OR
s=unicode('some string', 'utf-8')
isnum = s.isnumeric()
```

Or you can do this to change `word` into `string`:

```
x = str(word).isnumeric()
```

Comment: OP says it's with Python 3

Comment: Yeah? What is wrong then?

Comment: *that `u` isn't required to make a string literal a unicode string... `str` **is unicode***

Comment: `unicode()` also? Should I delete, that and just leave `str()` only? Then that also doesn't make any sense cuz `word` is also already string!

Comment: `unicode` **doesn't exist in Python 3** it's just `str`.and yes, calling `str` on a `str` is pointless

Comment: Then deleting answer is the best, right? Because after deleting everything, there is nothing left!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga additionally I have found that, for which question this is closed as duplicate, there answer are same as mine. That also doesn't make any sense, cuz if that doesn't solve the OP problem then why this question is closed without any answer?